# как сделать код разноцветным на своем сайте

Tags: php, html, css

```
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars;
// Outputs Saab,Volvo,BMW
```

Сверху три строчки которые я написал, разноцветные.
Как это правильно называеться когда для ключевых слов в языке программирования надается свой цвет, существует ли какой то фреймворk который можно установить на свой сайт, и что бы код тоже был разноцветным, или же нужно самому проверять весь код на слова, и находить ключевые слова и надавать им цвет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)